# How can I deserialize an influxDB JSON-query to look like a table using Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: c#, influxdb

I receive a JSON-Object from influxDB which contains the table content from the table "cpu", but the console shows up an unformatted string

```cs
{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"series":[{"name":"cpu","columns":["time","host","region","value"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:01.559815781Z","serverA","us_west",95],["2019-06-06T09:59:40.68601263Z","serverA","us_west",0.64],["2019-06-06T10:09:41.790446331Z","serverA","us_west",0.78]]}]}]}
```

Referencing to System.Web.Script.Serialization isn't an option because I'm using .NET Core.

I put the "pretty=true" to the EscapeUriString what helps me to get a better looking JSON result.

[Result after "pretty=true"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O690c.png)

The query i'll send can be different so creating a class isn't an option too

Thats my code for so long

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;

namespace InfluxDBQuery
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string influxURL = "http://172.29.213.151:8086/query";
            string database = "mydb";
            string pretty = "pretty=true&";

            var client = new WebClient();
            var queryString = Uri.EscapeUriString($"?{pretty}db={database}&q=SELECT * FROM cpu");
            var queryUrl = influxURL + queryString;
            var response = client.DownloadString(queryUrl);
            Console.WriteLine(response);

            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
            Console.WriteLine(json);

        }
    }
}
```

So how can i format the result from the InfluxDB-query to look like a table?

Comment: When you say "look like a table" - can you provide an example of what you want it to look like?

Comment: @chris yes, i want an output as like as the influx cli itself gives me when i type a query. i show it in this imgur link: [link](https://imgur.com/a/aejwKEc)